# Question about meaning of "knocking on the door" & "the guys"

Tags: word-meaning

> KOLKATA: A Grand Slam title may be eluding Roger Federer for two years but the 33-year-old can't be written off yet, his former coach Tony Roche said here on Tuesday. "I think he can play as long as he wants to on the mental side. Physically, I think he can play for another four-five years without any problem," said Roche. Asked about Federer adding another major to his record 17 titles, Roche said, "Another Slam definitely... Obviously, Wimbledon is his best chance but he's **knocking on the door** in last few Slams. As long as **the guys** still respect Roger, he is always going to be a threat," the Aussie told reporters on the sidelines of a seven-day camp at the Jaidip Mukerjea Tennis Academy here.

Firstly, is **knocking on the door** an idiom? What does it mean?

Secondly, does **the guys** here reffer to opponents? Is it again an idiom ir slang?

Comment: Side-note: In ordinary conversational English usage, one would say "…in the last few Slams", not "…in last few Slams". The error is in the original article; it might be a misquotation.

Comment: Based on context, what do you think *knocking on the door* could mean? It's based on the literal meaning. As for *guys* native speakers have to guess at its meaning. Opponents? Players? Sponsors? The whole tennis profession? Finally, did you copy-and-paste this,  because there seems to be some nonstandard grammar in it.

Comment: I think the particular idiom is "knocking *at* the door". Not that it matters much.

Comment: @CarSmack It appears to be of Indian origin - it's published on the Times of India and ZeeNews sites.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Knocking on the door** is figurative speech. It can mean a lot of things. Here, it means that Roger Federer has performed well enough in recent Slam tournaments that he is clearly a threat to win these tournaments in upcoming years. In the metaphor, the "door" means a sort of imaginary barrier through which a person passes when becoming champion. "Knocking" on it means being almost ready to go through it (perhaps if Fate or Opportunity open the door).
2. **The guys** is an idiom for the men who are well-known in some circle of friends—or, in this case, the circle of top-level tennis competitors. So, yes, it means Federer's opponents.

Comment: It seems to me Federer's chances of being a threat have nothing to do with whether his opponents respect him.

Comment: @CarSmack I agree. I don't think the coach is really making much sense. People often blabber without making much sense when talking about sports. Perhaps he meant to say something like "The guys still treat him with respect because they know he's still a threat" and just phrased it poorly because he was speaking off-the-cuff. It's hardly fair to someone who's trying to learn English!